# No database selected when importing

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have exported the database but then when I want to import again I get no database selected error

I know that the problem is solved by selecting the database, but I already exported the database, so I cannot import it directly.

Answer (score 0):

If your existing SQL file doesn't have a `USE <databasename>` statement, phpMyAdmin won't automatically know in to which database you wish to import the data. There are several solutions:

- Tell phpMyAdmin explicitly by first opening the database. You may have to create the database first (which is simple; two button presses and typing the name),
- Edit the SQL file to add the statement (this usually would be the first command in the file, and would look something like

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `foo` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
USE `foo`;
```

- Export the file again, from in phpMyAdmin you can check the box for "Add `CREATE DATABASE` / `USE` statement" and the generated file will include these statements for you.